# PHP MySQL how to do a more complex query

Tags: php, mysql

I have a module that I have created to use PHP, jQuery, and MySQL to search and return results.

I have 2 tables in the DB that I am trying to pull from: projects and clients. In the projects table a Client_ID is saved.

Now I am trying to retrieve the clientName WHERE projects.Client_ID = clients.Client_ID

Here is my code:

```
    $dbc = @mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass,
    $db_name);

if (!$dbc) {
    trigger_error('Could not connect to MySQL: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
}

if(isset($_GET['keyword'])){
    $keyword =  trim($_GET['keyword']) ;
$keyword = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $keyword);



$query = "SELECT projects.Client_ID, projects.projectNumber, projects.projectName, projects.projectManager, projects.expectedDate, projects.address, projects.CreationDate FROM projects WHERE projectNumber like '%$keyword%' or projectName like '%$keyword%' or address like '%$keyword%'";

$result = mysqli_query($dbc,$query);

if($result){
    if(mysqli_affected_rows($dbc)!=0){
     while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC)){

     echo '<li> <b>'.$row['projectNumber'].'</b> - '.$row['projectName'].
     '<table width=\"100%\">
        <tr >
                <td><b>Project Manager</b></td>
                <td><b></b></td>
                <td width=\"200px\"><b>Address</b></td>
                <td><b>Expected Date</b></td>
                <td><b>Created Date</b></td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td colSpan=\"5\"></td></tr>
        <tr>
                <td><i>'.$row['projectManager'].'</i></td>
                <td><i></i></td>
                <td><i>'.$row['address'].'</i></td>
                <td><i>'.$row['expectedDate'].'</i></td>
                <td><i>'.$row['CreationDate'].'</i></td>
        </tr>
</table>
     </li>
     <hr />'   ;
    }
    }else {
        echo 'No Results for :"'.$_GET['keyword'].'"';
    }

}
}else {
    echo 'Parameter Missing';
}




?>
```

I am lost. I have tried a lot of things on my own to no avail.

The GOAL is to show the clientName which is stored in the clients DB. The important code is the query.

If this is not clear please let me know what other details I can provide.

Comment: This question could be improved; describe what you intend to happen and whatever errors/results you're getting instead.

Comment: Matt, I explained the question. There are no errors. The intent is to show the clientName which is stored in the Client_ID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok if i understand correctly you require the client name from the client table, based on the client_ID from the projects table.

You will need to modify the sql query at line 15 to be

```
    $query = "SELECT clients.clientName, projects.Client_ID, projects.projectNumber, projects.projectName, projects.projectManager, projects.expectedDate, projects.address, projects.CreationDate 
    FROM projects 
    LEFT JOIN clients on projects.Client_id = clients.Client_ID
    WHERE projectNumber like '%$keyword%' or projectName like '%$keyword%' or address like '%$keyword%'";
```

And you will need to output it into the table somewhere , so in your loop where you are displaying data put in the variable

```
    $row['clientName']
```